# NSNotificationCenter not working, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access, nsnotificationcenter

i'm working with cocos3D (but that doesn't matters..)

```
@interface MyScene : CC3Scene
{
    MyObject *theObject;
    GameLogic *gLogic;
}
@implementation MyScene
-(void)initializeScene
{
    gLogic = [[[GameLogic alloc] init] autorelease];
    theObject = [[[MyObject alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self addChild:theObject];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:gLogic 
                                             selector:@selector(testHandler:) 
                                                 name:@"objectMoved" 
                                               object:theObject];
}
```

in GameLogic i have a simple notification handler (also declared in the header)...

```
-(void)testHandler:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Notification: %@", [notification name]);
}
```

and in MyObject, when it's time, i call this method

```
-(void)dispatchEvent
{
    NSLog(@"SHOULD DISPATCH THE EVENT");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"objectMoved" object:self];
    NSLog(@"EVENT DISPATCHED");
}
```

but it crashes highlighting the postNotificationName line...
the error is EXC_BAD_ACCESS meaning (if i understood right) that there's some reference to a deallocated object.......

what's happening?

Comment: commenting the `addObserver` line on MyScene, the method `dispatchEvent` is executed till the end without any error and everything still works... (except the `testHandler:` is obviously ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have two or more instances of `MyObject`, the one you are creating within `initializeScene` and the one that's posting the notification. Passing `nil` as the object parameter should work:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:gLogic 
                                         selector:@selector(testHandler:) 
                                             name:@"objectMoved" 
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: i'm still receiving the same error.. i've tried to use `nil` on `addOserver`, `postNotificationName` and both of them (on `object` parameter), but still not working

Comment: Maybe your observer (the `MyScene` instance) has been deallocated. Make sure to remove it as an observer during `dealloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that you're not actually calling `addObserver:selector:name:object:`. You don't have a logging line there; are you sure that code is running?

The second most likely cause is that you're calling removeObserver: before the notification is posted. This is most commonly in dealloc (which should always call `removeObserver` if you've ever observed anything). The error here would be that your observing object has deallocated before the notification.

Here in your code object is not set properly in `addObserver`

Comment: even if i comment or uncomment the `removeObserver` on `dealloc` method i still receive the error... anyway i'm not sure about what you're saying: why «object is not set properly»? why i'm «not actually calling addObserver...»

Comment: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:gLogic                               selector:@selector(testHandler:)                                  name:@"objectMoved" object:nil]; add this in ViewDidLoad method